# Как сохранить динамический дизайн страницы в localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня по клику на кнопку меняется дизайн страницы. Как мне сохранить его после перезагрузки через localStorage ?

```js
const swapColors = () => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item-link')
    items.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.toggle('item-link-swapped')
    });
}


const button = document.querySelector('.swap-colors');
button.addEventListener('click', swapColors);
```

```css
.main-menu .item-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #485863;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.main-menu .item-link-swapped{
    color: #e0008d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
}
```

Вот пример css, по нажатию на кнопку у меня меняется класс у элемента, мне надо сохранить этот класс после перезагрузки.

Comment: Может быть это вам поможет: `localStorage.setItem('layout', document.body.innerHTML)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Что-то не пойму....ТС знает про localStorage..... то есть может спокойно посмотреть методы в доках для сохранения данных и их взятия.......но вместо этого пишет вопрос.....странно.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Наверное не знал как взять всю страницу как строку :)

Comment: const swapColors = () => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item-link')
    items.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.toggle('item-link-swapped')
    });
    localStorage.removeItem('layout');
    localStorage.setItem('layout', document.body.innerHTML);
}


const button = document.querySelector('.swap-colors');
button.addEventListener('click', swapColors);



window.onload = () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('layout');
}

Теперь не работает сваппер (

@EzioMercer

Comment: Во первых никогда такие куски кода не вставляйте в комментарии, если нужно дополните ваш вопрос, нажав на кнопку Править под вопросом. Во вторых после вставки таким образом JS не будет работать. Надо все слушатели  ставить только после вставки из `localStorage`